# How can i disable selected checked in other to prevent another user from selecting it again

Tags: php, laravel

That is how i save my checked box to the database. I dont want the checked box to exist twice in the database

[image]

This is if a user select a checkbox another user should not be able to select the same check box again

Comment: Put your code in the question as text, not as an image of it.

Comment: Learn [how to use code block](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Why not filter for existing checkboxes before persisting?

Answer (score 0):

From the screenshot I understood that you don't want allocation of multiple lecturer on same unit of same department.

So before creating `allocated` row, you need to check those entries already exist or not.

```
$data = compact('course_id', 'department', 'unit');
// check the department and unit already assigned or not. 
if(!allocated::where($data)->exists()){
   $data['lecturers_name'] = $lecturers_name;
   allocated::create($data);
}
```

Comment: After putting the if statement, to check if record exist, it is only storing one value,

Answer (score -1):

For starters you did not gave any examples of your code. So my example later on will not be based on your code.

You can disable a checkbox but this is easy to bypass if someone really wants to. The inspector could be used to alter the html so the disabled checkbox becomes enabled. Of course you can validate this in the back-end.

I would choose to display only the checkboxes that have a value that has not been chosen yet by someone else. My example contains both solutions.

```
// create connection with your database.
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// array with values that can be picked.
$values = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Lemon'];

// loop trough the array.
foreach( $values as $fruit ) 
{
    // select query -> check if someone else already choose the fruit.
    $sql = "SELECT chosen_fruit FROM friends WHERE chosen_fruit = " . $fruit;

    // execute the query.
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    // if no results are found, meaning nobody else have picked this fruit yet.
    if ($result->num_rows == 0) {
        // enabled checkbox that is free to use
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chosen_fruit" value="' . $fruit . '">'
    } else {
        // disabled checkbox because this fruit has already been chosen.
        echo '<input type="checkbox" name="chosen_fruit" value="' . $fruit . '" disabled>'
    }
}
```

Edit: I saw your edit after posting my answer.